# Linking error in an xll context with visual studio : general linking issue or particular?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, unresolved-external, xll

I have `A.h` and `A.lib`. My project links to `A` in the sense that the path to `A.lib` is added into "additional libraries" path in visual studio (in "linker, general"), and `A.lib` is added in "linker input" in visual studio. All header and source files are in the same project.

Now, I have `B.h` and `B.cpp`. The latter includes `B.h` that includes `A.h`, and a function `f` declared in `B.h` has its definition in `B.cpp` that uses a function `g` declared in `A.h`.

At build, I have the following error message :

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol g referenced in function f
```

and I don't understand why this happens, accounting on the library linking I performed described above.

I added the tag `xll` because my problem happens in an xll context, and because this issue may be classic in an xll context. For xll people :

- `A.h` is `XLCALL.h`, `A.lib` is `XLCALL32.lib`
- `B.h` is `FRAMEWRK.h` and `B.cpp` is `FRAMEWRK.cpp`
- `f` is for instance `_TempActiveRef12` and `g` is `_Excel12` (or `f is`_Excel12f`and`g`is`_Excel12v@16`)

Comment: Sorry, wrongly swapped `f` and `g`, just correct the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `B.cpp` and used instead a `B.lib` furnished as well and removed my linker errors.